# Convert string to dateTime in SQL Server CASE function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, casting, type-conversion

I need to define a variable duedate to check when the client has to pay and i need it to calculate the amount that must be paid.

I defined the variable `@DueDate` which I am getting from conditions.

I get this error although I have tried to convert it to date and time.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetPayments, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My code:

```
 USE [Tenant Management]
 GO

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPayments] 
     @DueDate AS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @DueDate = 'select CASE rsp.[Frequency]  
                when ''1'' then CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 12, rs.Last_Payment) as datetime)
                when ''2'' then CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, rs.Last_Payment) as datetime)
                when ''3'' then CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 3, rs.Last_Payment) as datetime)
                when ''4'' then CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rs.Last_Payment) as datetime)
                end
                from [dbo].[Reservation_Price] rsp
                inner join [dbo].[Reservations] rs on rsp.Reservation_ID = rs.ID';

    SELECT
        prs.[First Name] + ' ' + prs.[Middle Name] + ' ' + prs.[Last Name] AS [Tenant],
        c.Name as [Channel Name],
        CASE rsp.[Frequency] 
           WHEN '1' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 12, rs.Last_Payment)
           WHEN '2' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 6, rs.Last_Payment)
           WHEN '3' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 3, rs.Last_Payment)     
           WHEN '4' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rs.Last_Payment)
        END AS [Next Payment Due],
        rs.[Actual Date in],
        @DueDate,
        DATEDIFF(MONTH, @DueDate, GETDATE()) * rsp.Price_Month AS [Amount to be paid],
        rs.Balance
    FROM
        [dbo].[Reservation_Price] rsp
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Reservations] rs ON rsp.Reservation_ID = rs.ID
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Person] prs ON rs.[Person ID] = prs.ID
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Channel] c ON rs.[Channel ID] = c.ID
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Reservation_Frequency] fq ON rsp.Frequency = fq.ID
    WHERE
        rsp.Date_From < GETDATE() 
        AND rsp.Date_To > DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rs.Last_Payment)
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you have defined @DueDate as a datetime and then you are trying to assign the value to the big select statement. That isn't how that works. Just put that case expression in your query. Not really sure why you are passing the @DueDate because you set it in your code. Here is how this likely should look.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPayments] 
 @DueDate AS DATETIME

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select prs.[First Name] + ' '+prs.[Middle Name]+' '+prs.[Last Name] as [Tenant],c.Name as [Channel Name]
        , CASE rsp.[Frequency] when '1' then DATEADD(MONTH, 12, rs.Last_Payment)
                                             when '2' then DATEADD(MONTH, 6, rs.Last_Payment)
                                             when '3' then DATEADD(MONTH, 3, rs.Last_Payment)       
                                             when '4' then DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rs.Last_Payment)
                                             end as [Next Payment Due]
        , rs.[Actual Date in]
        , DueDate = CASE rsp.[Frequency] --Frequency really a string? Seems like it should be an int
                when '1' then DATEADD(MONTH, 12, rs.Last_Payment) --casting the result of DATEADD to a datetime is redundant. It returns a datetime
                when '2' then DATEADD(MONTH, 6, rs.Last_Payment)
                when '3' then DATEADD(MONTH, 3, rs.Last_Payment)
                when '4' then DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rs.Last_Payment)
                end
        , DATEDIFF(MONTH,@DueDate,GETDATE())*rsp.Price_Month as [Amount to be paid]
        , rs.Balance
    from [dbo].[Reservation_Price] rsp
    inner join [dbo].[Reservations] rs on rsp.Reservation_ID = rs.ID
    inner join [dbo].[Person] prs on rs.[Person ID] = prs.ID
    inner join [dbo].[Channel] c on rs.[Channel ID] = c.ID
    inner join [dbo].[Reservation_Frequency] fq on rsp.Frequency = fq.ID
    where rsp.Date_From<GETDATE() and rsp.Date_To > DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rs.Last_Payment)

END
```